# How to convert VIDEO_TS folder to video format

Tags: 11.10, video

I have a movie directory with a sub directory VIDEO_TS in it. I want to convert this to a video file like avi, mp4, etc... How can I convert this?

Right now I can see it with VLC of course but I want to have it as a one file video format.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[HandBrake](http://handbrake.fr/) is a general-purpose, open-source, cross-platform, multithreaded video transcoder software application which is more than capable of reading the VIDEO_TS folder and converting it to a file format of your choice.

Comment: Mind that [this](https://github.com/HandBrake/HandBrake/issues/3186) indicates that HandBrake will drop any menus present on the DVD.

Answer (score 34):

FFmpeg also works quite well:

```
cat ./VIDEO_TS/*.VOB | ffmpeg -i - <out_name>.<out_format>
```

Source:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/FFmpeg#VOB_to_any_container

Comment: `ffmpeg -i "concat:VTS_01_1.VOB|VTS_01_2.VOB|VTS_01_3.VOB|VTS_01_4.VOB|VTS_01_5.VOB" outfile.mp4` works on both linux and windows [source](http://www.tech-g.com/2017/01/15/converting-dvd-to-mp4-h264-on-windows/)

Answer (score 1):

[K9Copy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K9Copy) is a powerful tool that can read a VIDEO_TS directory structure (or a DVD) and produce (re-encode) MPEG-4 video files. It also supports MPEG-2 extraction, which is useful for creating lossless backups (one MPEG-2 video file will be created for every episode/video on the DVD). It is possible to only copy the English audio track and subtitles.

To install [K9Copy on Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/K9Copy), you need to enable the multiverse repository, either by changing the config file or by using the Software Sources gui. Other distributions like Fedora have it in their default repository.